# May I set a checkbox from another form?

Tags: codenameone

In form1 there is a checkbox.
Now currently there is form2 active. May I set the checkbox in form1 
from an active form2 ?

Background:
From a Storage, I will do some initial settings at start of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to the `CheckBox` object it's just `cb.setSelected(true)`.

I'm assuming this is an old GUI builder application in which case you would need to set a variable X and then in the before show of form 1 just call:

```
findMyCheckBox(f).setSelected(X);
```